# where I should initiate and connect socket.io in React Native component?

Tags: react-native, express, websocket, socket.io, chat

i now learning socket.io to build a chat app with React Native that contain private messaging like line/whatsapp, user can add another user to their friendlist, and can start chat with them...

Here's my Stack Navigation looks like:

```js
class MainNavigator extends Component {
  render() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {user.username ? (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="ChatList" component={ChatList} options={{ title: 'Chatz' }} />
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Chat"
              component={Chat}
              options={{ title: `Chat as "${user.username}"` }}
            />
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator >
    );
  }
}
```

You can see that if there is a user logged in in my app, stack navigator only contain `ChatList` and `Chat`, where the `ChatList` is a list of all active `Chat`s.

I know that to connect a socket to backend we simply connect it with `socket = io(http://localhost:3000)`, but where i should connect it in my components?
I'll use the socket in `ChatList` and `Chat` component.

Should i connect it in both of the component constructor like this?

```js
class ChatList extends Component {
  constuctor(props) {
    super()
    this.socket = io('localhost:3000');
  }
  
  .......
}

class Chat extends Component {
  constuctor(props) {
    super()
    this.socket = io('localhost:3000');
  }
  
  .......
}
```

Or somewhere else just once? Because if i did it like above, it connecting several times to my express backend...

Answer (score 1):

You should only connect to socket server once and switch connection when needed. My suggestion is create a class service that control connection logic and all component that need to listen to this connection channel will subcribe to the service. Example:

```js
class SocketService {
   constructor() {
      this.connection = null
      this.listener = []
   }

   connect(server) {
      this.connection = io(server)
      this.connection.<on_receive_messages> = this.onMessageReceived(data) 
   }

   addListener(identify, callback = () => {}) {
      this.listener[identify] = callback
   }
   
   removeListener(identify) {
      delete this.listener[identify]
   }
   
   onMessageReceived(data) {
      this.listener.map(callback => callback(data))
   }  ​
}
```

Then once user logged in, let connect your service

```js
   onUserLoggedIn() {
      socket = new SocketService();
      socket.connect("localhost:3000");
      navigation.navigate("ChatList");
   }
```

And inside your component

```js
class ChatList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
     socket.addListener("ChatList", (message) => {
        Alert.alert("message", message)
     })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    socket.removeListener("ChatList");
  }
  
  .......
}

class Chat extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
     socket.<switch_channel_or_something>
     socket.addListener("Chat", (message) => {
        Alert.alert("message", message)
     })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    socket.removeListener("Chat");
  }
}
```

It's not a complete code but you might get the idea